# How to remove specific layer in multi-dimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array where I would like to remove a specific layer of the data. Basically, I would like to remove all the labels that are numeric aka the [0] => Array, [1] => Array, [2] => Array, and [3] => Array.

Here's the array I have currently:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CN=Abraham Lincoln,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io] => Array
                (
                    [objectclass] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => top
                            [1] => person
                            [2] => organizationalPerson
                            [3] => user
                        )
                    [cn] => Abraham Lincoln
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io] => Array
                (
                    [objectclass] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => top
                            [1] => person
                            [2] => organizationalPerson
                            [3] => user
                        )
                    [distinguishedname] => CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CN=CloudNCUsers,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io] => Array
                (
                    [objectclass] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => top
                            [1] => group
                        )
                    [distinguishedname] => CN=CloudNCUsers,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CN=Jill Dope,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io] => Array
                (
                    [objectclass] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => top
                            [1] => person
                            [2] => organizationalPerson
                            [3] => user
                        )
                    [distinguishedname] => CN=Jill Dope,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io
                )

        )
)
```

Here's the array I need:

```
Array
(
    [CN=Abraham Lincoln,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io] => Array
        (
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => top
                    [1] => person
                    [2] => organizationalPerson
                    [3] => user
                )
            [cn] => Abraham Lincoln
            )
       )

    [CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io] => Array
        (
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => top
                    [1] => person
                    [2] => organizationalPerson
                    [3] => user
                )
                [distinguishedname] => CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io
         )


    [CN=CloudNCUsers,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io] => Array
        (
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => top
                    [1] => group
                )
        )

    [CN=Jill Dope,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io] => Array
        (
            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => top
                    [1] => person
                    [2] => organizationalPerson
                    [3] => user
                )
             [distinguishedname] => CN=Jill Dope,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io
        )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how are you making the array? fix it thereby not pushing to a new array but instead using the key you want

Comment: first initialise a new container, then use a foreach. use reset function to target the sub array values and key function to target the key, and finally simply assign them into the new container. be careful though, if you expect multiple values on each sub group then you'll overwrite it to the last value.

Comment: Essentially, how I'm making this array would result in the same issue if I tried to do it again. I basically do a query to an LDAP server, then save that search result by doing the following: $array[] = ldap_get_entries($ldapconnection, $result);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a level from the array using [`key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) and [`reset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and saving to a new array:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $result[key($entry)] = reset($entry);
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FVT7l)

You should be able to do the same thing when you initially load the array to save this extra step:

```
$entry = ldap_get_entries($ldapconnection, $result);
$array[key($entry)] = reset($entry);
```

Note that this assumes that all of the key values (`CN=Abraham Lincoln,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=io` etc.) are unique. If they are not, later values in the array will overwrite earlier ones in the output. Note also that if `ldap_get_entries` returns more than one value, this will remove all but the first. However based on your existing code and the sample data you have provided, it would appear that this is not the case.